# convert debian-logo.jpg -crop 16x16-16-16 debian_crop.jpg error

Tags: imagemagick

I want to cut an image called debian-logo.jpg with the following command:

```
convert debian-logo.jpg -crop 16x16-16-16 debian_crop.jpg
```

But for some reason there is an error. Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

How big is your input jpg? Using negative crop offsets in ImageMagick only works with -gravity center (and sizes larger than 32x32). Otherwise, the crop will be off the image bounds for any other gravity setting. Crops are always relative to the gravity setting, which defaults to the -gravity northwest. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_gravity

If you want to crop inside the image with an offset, then the crop offsets need to be positive and will be cropped inside using positive offsets, even with -gravity south, east etc. The positive offset move inward relative the corner or side indicated by the gravity setting.

Are you trying to extend and pad the image in some direction with the crop. If so, then use

```
convert debian-logo.jpg -background black -gravity northwest -extent 16x16-16-16 debian_crop.jpg
```